How to change tab borderTopColor when using expo router tabs?
User press tab one will change tab one borderTopColor also press tab two will change tab two borderTopColor
I try to set tabBarStyle and listener under <Tab.Screen />
My problem is tabBarStyle effects one and two, event I just set it in tab one.
and there is no setOptions I can use in listeners
Here is my tabs setting:
// (app)/(tabs)/_layout.tsx


import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import useThemeColor from '@/common/hooks/useThemeColor';

export default function TabLayout() {
    const mainColor = useThemeColor('mainColor');
    const tabBackgroundColor = useThemeColor('tabBackgroundColor');

    return (
        <Tabs
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarActiveTintColor: mainColor,
                tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 20 },
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: tabBackgroundColor,
                },
                tabBarLabelPosition: 'beside-icon',
            }}
        >
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="one"
                options={{
                    title: 'Tab One',
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Image
                            tintColor={color}
                            resizeMode="contain"
                            style={{ width: 26, height: 26 }}
                            source={require('@/assets/images/group.png')}
                        />
                    ),
                    tabBarStyle: { borderTopColor: 'blue', borderTopWidth: 6 },
                }}
                listeners={{
                    tabPress: e => {
                        console.log('tabPress', e);
                        e.target.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { borderTopColor: 'green', borderTopWidth: 6 } });
                    },
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="two"
                options={{
                    title: 'Tab two',
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Image
                            tintColor={color}
                            resizeMode="contain"
                            style={{ width: 26, height: 26 }}
                            source={require('@/assets/images/vector.png')}
                        />
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </Tabs>
    );
}


you can use borderTopWidth: 0 or borderTopColor: "transparent":
 <Tabs
        screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: mainColor,
            tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 20 },
            tabBarStyle: {
                backgroundColor: tabBackgroundColor,
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                borderTopColor: "transparent"
            },
            tabBarLabelPosition: 'beside-icon',
            
        }}
    >

